# Assignment problem given a set of constraints

Tags: python, math, optimization, mathematical-optimization

Lets say i have a set of tuples, Where first index stands for an set and second index is the value for this particular item in that set. I want to choose the combination of tuples so that i maximize the sum of the second indexes given the constraints:

Number of sets has to be lower than a given random number.

Number of tuples has to be equal to a given random number.

Does anyone recouldnize this problem as an classic optimization-problem? and secondly, any suggestions on how to go on about this?

Bruteforce:
create all combinations and eliminate those that doesnt fulfill the constraints... and then choose the maximum sum. This is doable for smaller lists but my lists tends to be really large, such large that just creating the combinations with itertools maxes out the cpu.

What i tried so far in python:

```
def _testing(self, ranks, nroftuples, maxnrofsets):
        tuplelist = [(rank.identifier, rank.factor, ctr) for ctr, rank in enumerate(ranks)]
        import itertools
        allcombinations = list(itertools.combinations(tuplelist, nroftuples))
        filtered = [x for x in allcombinations if len(set([onetuple[0] for onetuple in x])) <= maxnrofsets]
        maxtuple = filtered[0]
        maxsum = sum([onetuple[1] for onetuple in maxtuple])
        for onetuple in filtered:
            if sum([insidetuple[1] for insidetuple in onetuple]) > maxsum:
                maxtuple = onetuple
                maxsum = sum([insidetuple[1] for insidetuple in onetuple])
        return maxtuple
```

Comment: Can you describe the optimization task a bit better, e.g. including a small input example and the solution? For me, it sounds a bit like the [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). What could help is the technique of [Simulated Annealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing)

Comment: Please add some data to play with. The description is not precise enough

Answer (score 1):

The constraints make this a bit non-standard but in a way this is definitely close to some classic optimization problems like:

- bin packing
- knapsack

Let's change the "set" language a bit because that is confusing with the set we're trying to build... So you have items, and each item has a *value* and a *class*.

You want to pick *exactly* N items, from *at most* M different classes, such that the total value is maximized.

Let's see. There's a trivial case when the top N items, by value, belong to at most M different classes. In that case just pick those items and you're done.

It only gets tricky when you have to pick the "right" classes. Like, what if the highest value item is in one class that otherwise only has low value items, right?

I feel that the *general* case might be NP-hard, which means an exact algorithm will be costly, like in your brute force case. But we can try heuristics:

- There's an obvious *greedy* approach: Start loading the highest value item. Then, as long as you're still below the class limit, keep adding hte next-highest value item. Keep going until you hit the class limit. Now fill up the rest of your items from among the highest value items of the classes you picked.
- In another greedy approach, you'd just compute the total value offered by each class, and then grab the top classes from that ranking and then pick your items among those.
- You should be able to express the whole thing as a linear integer program:

For each item you get a binary variable that's 0 if you don't pick the item and 1 if you do. Let's call those variables `x[i]`. Let's also add a variable for each *class*, call it `c[k]`.

Now we have an objective function `sum(x[i] * value[i])`, that we want to maximize. And we have a number of constraints:

- `sum(x[i]) == N` i.e. pick exactly `N` items.
- `sum(c[k)] <= M` i.e. pick at most `M` classes.
- Now we need a little math to make sure that `c[k]` is "active" if we have items from that class and 0 otherwise:

So for each class, grab the variables `x_k[i]` that belong to items of that class. Then add a bunch of constraints: `c[k] >= x_k[i]` which says that as soon as at least one item from class `k` was chosen, `c[k]` *must* be 1. Technically we'd also want to enforce that `c[k]` must be 0 if no items from that class were chosen, but we don't need that, because the optimizer will try to set `c[k]` to 0 anyway to satisfy the constraint.

Anyway, you figure out this math formulation, then grab an integer programming solver like CPLEX or MIP https://pypi.org/project/mip/ and express the problem and then have it solved for you.

If you want to turn this into a fun and weird project, try solving it on the D-Wave quantum computer. Their free trial might include enough comptue power for that :D It's already a binary optimization problem now you just need to follow their tutorials for dealing with constraints.

I'm trying to think if dynamic programming could work here, but maybe the keeping track of which classes were picked already would make the recursion relation quite complicated...

If neither the integer programming nor the quantum computing work well, there might be something to be done with *local search heuristics* such as simulated annealing...

Anyway, that's my thoughts. Maybe I am wildly overcomplicating this and there *is* a simple algorithmic solution,